# Showing error whenever optional props are being sent to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, react-table

I am trying to optional have row-select features and this should be determined based on a prop that is being passed from parent. I have two grids on a single page, where in one has prop that should enable row selection and the other one does not. But I am getting this error "Cannot read property 'className' of undefined " .

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-alternate-single-row-working-5fr81

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import DataGrid from "./DataGrid";
import ShowMore from "./ShowMore";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      columns: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.getColumns();
  }

  getData = () => {
    const data = [
      { firstName: "Jack", status: "Submitted", items: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
      { firstName: "Simon", status: "Pending", items: [1, 2] },
      { firstName: "Syls", status: "Pending", items: [1] },
      { firstName: "Pete", status: "Approved", items: [] }
    ];
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  getColumns = () => {
    const columns = [
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "status"
      },
      {
        Header: "Items",
        accessor: "items",
        Cell: row => <ShowMore value={row.value} />
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  };

  onClickRow = rowInfo => {
    this.setState({ allData: rowInfo }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.allData);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <DataGrid
          data={this.state.data}
          columns={this.state.columns}
          rowClicked={this.onClickRow}
        />
        <DataGrid data={this.state.data} columns={this.state.columns} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: All the code you provided is meaningless to find an error, Codesandbox provides all required information which line caused an error, so just follow it... Obviously in line  "const trProps = _.splitProps(getTrProps(finalState, undefined, undefined, this)) " getTrProps returns undefined, so just debug it to realize why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onRowClick` function in `DataGrid.js`, your function will return nothing on first render (or until something is clicked). ReactTable is expecting SOMETHING here. If you supply an empty object, it will successfully render.